# What is going on with bootstrap button outlines?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11, outline

This CSS rule in bootstrap.min is causing a dotted outline to appear on the left and bottom edge of buttons in IE 11 (IMO it looks terrible, like some kind of graphics glitch), but it does not appear at all in Firefox or Chrome:

```
.btn.active.focus,.btn.active:focus,.btn.focus,.btn:active.focus,.btn:active:focus,.btn:focus{
   outline:thin dotted;
   outline:5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
   outline-offset:-2px
}
```

Why is *outline* specified 3 times, and how is IE handling it differently than Chrome and Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

By the time, you might get the solution for your question.

I have used below code to fix my IE10 & IE11 styling issues. These are the conditional styles for IE. This could be useful for future references.

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    button:focus{
        outline:1px dotted #ccc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to deal with this stuff :/

You have 2 different properties here: `outline`, and `outline-offset`.

For each property, the last value that a browser understands is what will be applied. So, for the property `outline`, Chrome and Firefox understand the value `5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;`, which comes after the value `thin dotted`, so Chrome and Firefox apply the value `5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color` to the `outline` property. IE does not understand that value, so it applies the value `thin dotted`.

[IE does not support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-offset#Browser_Compatibility) outline-offset, which is why you see the outline on the left and bottom edge but not the rest.  To get the outline to show all around, I added a margin.